# Multiple User Login Redirect Page Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session

I want to create multiple user logins but with a different redirect page from each user level, there are 2 levels fyi, in my code can only redirect on 1 page, no matter that level 1 or 2 login is still directed to one page, what I want is that each level has its own page.. this is my code, please help me thank you

```
public function process()
  {
    $post = $this->input->post(null, TRUE);
    if(isset($post['login'])) {
      $this->load->model('m_user');
      $query = $this->m_user->login($post);
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $row = $query->row();
        $params = array(
          'userid' => $row->id_user,
          'level' => $row->level
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($params);
        echo "<script>
          alert('Login success');
          window.location='".site_url('klien')."';
        </script>";

      } else {
        echo "<script>
          alert('Login failed, wrong username/password');
          window.location='".site_url('auth/login')."';
        </script>";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you, please, describe, what is exactly the problem you are encountering with your code?

Comment: in my code can only redirect on 1 page, no matter that level 1 or 2 login is still directed to one page, what I want is that each level has its own page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging in, specify in the redirect URL which page it will go to according to the level condition:

```
public function process() {
    $post = $this->input->post(null, TRUE);
    if (isset($post['login'])) {
        $this->load->model('m_user');
        $query = $this->m_user->login($post);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            $params = array(
                'userid' => $row->id_user,
                'level' => $row->level
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($params);
            echo "<script>alert('Login success');</script>";

            if($row->level == 1) // Level condition to redirect specific page with example level 1
                redirect('/pageX');
            else if($row->level == 2) // Level condition to redirect specific page with example level 2
                redirect('/pageY');
            //... more levels = more conditions
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Login failed, wrong username/password');</script>";
            redirect(site_url('auth/login'));
        }
    }
}
```